# Find vowels using grep command

Tags: grep

How do i find three vowels in a row in a given file(not counting Roman numerals as words, and not counting "Y" as a vowel)?

Answer (score 3):

Using just grep, you can do:

```
grep -E '[aeiouAEIOU]{3}'
```

This finds three vowels in a row.

To disallow Roman numerals, and *only* **valid** Roman numerals (i.e. VI, VII, IX, XIV, are all valid, but VIX is not) you need a much more complicated setup and probably shouldn't be using just grep.

Comment: it is printing each line for the word that contains three vowels in a row. Is there any way to make it print total number of such instances(words contains three vowels in a row) in a given file ?

Comment: You can count *lines* containing three vowels in a row with `grep`—see `man grep`.  Just add the `-c` option.  However, if you want to count individual words and you have more than one word per line, you're using the wrong tool.  Try learning `awk`.  (`sed` is simpler, but won't handle requirements to count things.)

Comment: Sure, i will try to learn awk. Thank you for your help.

Comment: To count the number of occurrences of 3 vowels, as opposed to the _number of lines_ that contain one or more such occurrences, use `grep -oE '[aeiouAEIOU]{3}' test | wc -l`